# VBA button action issue on cell edit

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel toolbar created by VBA macros. When cell is in edit mode, I'm unable to perform any toolbar actions, the event itself is not getting triggered. Button events are getting triggered when we come out of that editing cell.

Is there any way to handle this? I want to allow users to click on buttons even when cell is in editing mode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

VBA will never run if a cell is in edit mode. If you are typing inside a cell, VBA is halted. Infact, if you press ALT + F11 and bring up the VBA editor window, and then go to edit a cell in Excel, you'll find you cant ALT + TAB back to the editor, it's gone. You cant even get back to the editor whilst you are in edit mode. (Obviously when you click outside Excel, the cell is no longer in edit mode, so you can select it from the windows tray)

You may have to use a form to allow users to edit cells, this way VBA will still run whilst the form text box is being typed in. Then submit it to the cell when the text box is complete

Comment: Thanks SilverShotBee for the reply. Yes VBA is not allowing to switch between the tabs or even open the developer window when cell is in edit mode. I think this is the default behaviour of excel.         In our case, we can't use a form for cell editing, we need to allow the users to edit the excel cells and then click on toolbar buttons.       Is there anyway this is handled in any vba applicaiton.